# Can a pointer field, to "user" class, be updated via rest api?

Tags: parse-platform

I have a class *A* that has a pointer (pointer field) to the special class *User*. Is it possible to automatically update the pointer field with the authenticated user, using the Rest API instead of having to call the API like the example bellow?

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ${REST_API_KEY}" \
  -H "X-Parse-Session-Token: ${SESSION_TOKEN}" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"user":{ "__type": "Pointer", "className": "_User", "objectId": "${id}"}}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/A
```

I would like to update the *User* field by just using the call:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ${REST_API_KEY}" \
  -H "X-Parse-Session-Token: ${SESSION_TOKEN}" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/A
```

And an *A* entry would be created.

```
A : {Pointer<_User> user_from_session, string objectId}
```

Any enlightenment is appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to accomplish what I wanted by adding an afterSave trigger. When creating *A*, with an authenticated request, I will read the current user from the session and set the field in the class. Bellow the example.

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("A", function (request, response) {

    var record = request.object;

    var user = Parse.User.current();

    if (record.existed() == false) {

        record.set("user", user);

        record.save().
            then(function (record) {
                response.success();

            }, function (error) {
                response.error();

            });

    } else {
        console.log("[DEBUG] Normal save (A).");
        response.success();
    }
});
```

Cheers.